# Return a cell value/reference

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a sheet which automatically calculates a ratio based on a couple inputs, this ratio then corresponds to a listed rate. What I would like to do is add a formula to a cell so that it automatically populates a rate based on a ratio rather than having to manually match it up and enter it.

For example I want the formula to be in cell D25 and if D24 equals the value of G20, I would like D25 to then display the value of cell I20. If D24 equals the value of G21, I would like D25 to display the value of cell I21, and so on with a total of 10 different rates/ratios. Is there any formulas to do something like this? I have tried a few and looked around and can't seem to find one that works. Preferably being able to use cell references so that if the ratio/rate changes it can be adjusted more easily than having to adjust the actual formula.

Comment: You should be able to use one or more of the lookup functions (VLOOKUP or combining INDEX/MATCH)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need VLookup:

```
=VLookup (D24, G20:I29, 3, False)
```

Comment: Thanks that worked. I tried a few tests and occasionally came back with an N/A, changing from FALSE to TRUE seems to have fixed that however.

Comment: Just so you are aware, that `True` / `False` switch tells Excel whether to look for an approximate match or an exact match. The reason for the `N/A` result is because it couldn't find an exact match for your ratio. Changing to `True` means that if it doesn't find an exact match, Excel will use the last value it finds in your list that is lower than the value you're looking up. For this to work correctly your list has to be sorted by the lookup values. If your lookup list is 3, 7, 12, 5, 10 and you lookup 10 with the `True` setting, you'll get the 7 result back, even though 10 is in the list.

Comment: Correction: it will return the value before the first one that is higher than what you're looking for. So in that example above, 12 is the first value it finds that is higher than the 10 that you're looking for, so it goes back to the 7. If the value you're looking for is higher than anything in the list, you'll get the last one back, so looking for 20 in the unsorted list 3, 7, 10, 19, 6 will return 6, even though 19 is a closer match. If the value you're looking for is lower than anything in the list you'll get `#N/A` again.